# no matching function for call to ‘begin(int [n])’

Tags: c++, arrays, reverse

I tried many things but still, it's giving an error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘begin(int [n])’
```

What's the best approach?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    reverse(begin(arr), end(arr));
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        cout << arr[j] <<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: change `int arr[n];` to `std::vector<int> arr(n);`.  VLA's (`int arr[n]`) are not standard in C++.

Comment: "`cin >> n;
    int arr[n] ;`" - variable length arrays are *not* supported by standard C++. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: Are you compiling your code as modern C++ (C++11/C++14/C++17)? Otherwise that `begin(arr)` has *no* chance of working.

Comment: And once you've changed to a `std::vector`, and if all you want to do is to print the input in reverse, then use the vectors reverse iterators `rbegin` and `rend` instead.

Comment: "`using namespace std;`" - bad habit.

Comment: Stuff like `int arr[n]` isn't valid C++, because [C++ doesn't have variable length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/9254539). Your code only compiles because of a GCC non-standard extension. You should use an `std::vector` instead to make your code portable and avoid blowing out the stack.

Answer (score 3):

> error:no matching function for call to ‘begin(int [n])’

This is because of that you have used **non-standard** [**Variable Length Array**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-length-arrays-in-c-and-c/), here:

```
cin >> n;
int arr[n] ;
```

Therefore, it's not possible to apply the standard algorithms like `std::reverse` to this kind of non-standard arrays.

if you change it normal array with a size, like:

```
const int n = 3;
int arr[n] ;
```

The code what you wrote is valid and will work. [**<kbd>See here</kbd>**](https://www.ideone.com/AaoWmp)

However, now you can not input the size of the array.

---

> Whats the best approach?

Use [**`std::vector`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Now you also have the option for reverse printing without using `std::reverse`, but using `std::vector::reverse_iterator`.(If that's all you wanted)

For instance: [**<kbd>See output here</kbd>**](https://www.ideone.com/K0strr)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
   int n;
   std::cin >> n;
   std::vector<int> arr(n);
   for(int& ele: arr) std::cin >> ele;
   //std::reverse(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
   //for(const int ele: arr) std::cout << ele << " ";
   //or simply
   std::for_each(arr.rbegin(), arr.rend(),[](const int ele){ std::cout << ele << " "; });
   return 0;
}
```