# Fixed-size array as function parameter: No matching function for call to 'begin'

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

I am passing a fixed size array to a function (the size is defined to a constant in the function's definition). However, I still get the error

> No matching function for call to 'begin'

```
# define arr_size 2
void test(int arr0[2]){
    int arr1[]={1,2,3};
    int arr2[arr_size];
    
    begin(arr0); // does not work -- how can I make this work?
    begin(arr1); // works
    begin(arr2); // works
}
```

There is a related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51638149/no-matching-function-for-call-to-beginint-n), however, the array's size was clearly not constant in that case. I want to avoid using vectors (as suggested there) for efficiency reasons.

Does anyone know what the issues is?

Comment: If you want to avoid `std::vector` and always have a fixed size you could use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (it's just a wrapper around a c-style array) - and can be passed to functions by value without problems (in contrast to c-style arrays wich will decay into pointers like @Vlad from Moscow explained in his answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function declaration

```
void test(int arr0[2]){
```

is equivalent to

```
void test(int *arr0){
```

because the compiler adjusts parameters having array types to pointers to array element types.

That is the both declarations declare the same one function.

You may even write for example

```
void test(int arr0[2]);

void test(int *arr0){
    //,,,
}
```

So you are trying to call the function `begin` for a pointer

```
begin(arr0);
```

You could declare the parameter as a reference to the array type

```
void test(int ( &arr0 )[2]){
```

to suppress the implicit conversion from an array to a pointer.